Trying to merge two datasets with matching values but losing column that had no matching values
Im trying to merge two datasets that I have. They are very large files (3.8 million lines) and I cannot just simply merge these files....
the two data sets look like this
Dataset 1:



X1
X2
X3
X4
X5
X6
X7
X8
X9
X10
X11
X12




chr
source
type
min
max
length
strand
value
DataA
DataD
DataG
DataJ


chr
source
type
min
max
length
strand
value
DataB
DataE
DataH
DataK


chr
source
type
min
max
length
strand
value
DataC
DataF
DataI
DataL



ds1 <- data.table(X1= c(chr, chr, chr), X2= c(source, source, source), X3= c(type, type, type), X4= c(min, min, min), X5= c(max, max, max), X6= c(length, length, length), X7= c(strand, strand, strand), X8= c(value, value, value), X9= c(DataA, DataB, DataC), X10= c(DataD, DataE, DataF), X11= c(DataG, DataH, DataI), X12= c(DataJ, DataK, DataL))

Dataset 2:



X9
X10
X11
X12
X13




DataA
DataD
DataG
DataJ
11111


DataB
DataE
DataH
DataK
22222


DataC
DataF
DataI
DataL
33333



ds2 <- data.table(X9= c(DataA, DataB, DataC), X10= c(DataD, DataE, DataF), X11= c(DataG, DataH, DataI), X12= c(DataJ, DataK, DataL), X13= c(11111, 22222, 33333))

With the lines of code I've tried (merge, inner and outer joins, cbind,  reduce, etc.) even after I have changed every parameter setting and specified which columns to merge by to get my desired outcome I keep getting outputs that look like this or slight variations on this (where the NAs fill different columns):
Output:



X1
X2
X3
X4
X5
X6
X7
X8
X9
X10
X11
X12
X13




chr
source
type
min
max
length
strand
value
DataA
DataD
DataG
DataJ
NA


chr
source
type
min
max
length
strand
value
DataB
DataE
DataH
DataK
NA


chr
source
type
min
max
length
strand
value
DataC
DataF
DataI
DataL
NA



However I am needing to keep the numerical values in column X13 from dataset 2. I am wanting something that looks like this:
Desired output:



X1
X2
X3
X4
X5
X6
X7
X8
X9
X10
X11
X12
X13




chr
source
type
min
max
length
strand
value
DataA
DataD
DataG
DataJ
11111


chr
source
type
min
max
length
strand
value
DataB
DataE
DataH
DataK
22222


chr
source
type
min
max
length
strand
value
DataC
DataF
DataI
DataL
33333



I am new to R and am very confused and frustrated... I've been trying to figure this out for over a week on my own and Im still so lost. The closest I've been able to get was with left join that gave the exact output as above with column X13 filled with NAs. Full join was also kind of close however it doubled my table size from 3.8 million lines to 7.6 million lines with the first 3.8 million lines looking like the output above with column X13 filled with NAs and the last 3.8 million lines having columns X1-X8 filled with NAs.
left join code to get output shown above:
merged_data <- left_join(df1, df2, by = c('X9', 'X10', 'X11', 'X12'))

full join code to get output mentioned:
merged_data <- full_join(df1, df2, by = c('X9', 'X10', 'X11', 'X12'))

If anyone has any suggestions that would be great!
Thank you!!!
****Edit: Its important to note that the data in the columns are unique in each row of the columns I am trying to join by (X9-X12). I have provided an updated version. Again, the issue I am having is the NA values in column X13. These values are the most important part of my data and I need them to be mapped to their respective positions that are provided in dataset 1. I have tried many different remedies, as I have been trying to solve this for over a week, so providing every example of the lines of code I've tried is not feasible in this case. Thank you for your understanding and help.

You need to define the "join by columns" more succinctly. As it is, you're trying to join using a many-many relationship, which is never going to get your desired output.

My actual data is unique in every row of each column. the example I provided is not at all what my working data looks like...

The reason your join is not working is that the "dummy" data in the identifying columns X9:X12 is NOT unique for each row (the warning message tells you this). You can bypass this with the relationship="many-to-many" argument but I doubt this is what you require with the real data.
This works:
library(data.table)
library(Hmisc)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'Hmisc'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     format.pval, units


suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse))

ds12 <- data.table(X1= Cs(chr, chr, chr), 
                  X2= Cs(source, source, source), 
                  X3= Cs(type, type, type), 
                  X4= Cs(min, min, min), 
                  X5= Cs(max, max, max), 
                  X6= Cs(length, length, length), 
                  X7= Cs(strand, strand, strand), 
                  X8= Cs(value, value, value), 
                  X9= Cs(DataA1, DataA2, DataA3), # Modified
                  X10= Cs(DataB, DataB, DataB), 
                  X11= Cs(DataC, DataC, DataC), 
                  X12= Cs(DataD, DataD, DataD))

ds22 <- data.table(X9= Cs(DataA1, DataA2, DataA3), # Modified
                  X10= Cs(DataB, DataB, DataB), 
                  X11= Cs(DataC, DataC, DataC), 
                  X12= Cs(DataD, DataD, DataD), 
                  X13= c(111, 222, 333))           # Check values

left_join(ds12, ds22, by = c('X9', 'X10', 'X11', 'X12'))
#>        X1     X2     X3     X4     X5     X6     X7     X8     X9    X10    X11
#>    <char> <char> <char> <char> <char> <char> <char> <char> <char> <char> <char>
#> 1:    chr source   type    min    max length strand  value DataA1  DataB  DataC
#> 2:    chr source   type    min    max length strand  value DataA2  DataB  DataC
#> 3:    chr source   type    min    max length strand  value DataA3  DataB  DataC
#>       X12   X13
#>    <char> <num>
#> 1:  DataD   111
#> 2:  DataD   222
#> 3:  DataD   333

Created on 2024-07-02 with reprex v2.1.0

This doesn't answer the question. You're simply bypassing an important warning message. And why load the Hmisc package?

That seems a bit harsh, Edward. I was trying to produce a decent reprex so that the OP could see that unique identifier values allow a one-to-one relationship for the join. Hmisc::Cs() allows unquoted string construction building on the code that was originally posted.

You've changed the OP's data to obtain the desired answer.

The points about the duplicated join columns and many-to-many relationship are true. I thought the modified data in this answer as a counter-example helps show this. However, it doesn't explain the NA values showing in X13. Join columns with duplicated values should join on each duplicate. In OP's example there are three rows with duplicated join columns in each dataset. That should result in 3x3 = 9 rows with duplicated join columns and additional columns (in this case all X13 = 12345).

A clue is that in the full_join the number of rows of data are duplicating (3.8mil to 7.6mil), so I suspect your join columns are not really joining anything. The X13 with NA is from the dataset without the X13 column and the X1-X8 columns with NAs are likely not present in the other dataset. Check the join columns and present a reprex that shows exactly what you are doing.

The example data I provided is unique in every row of columns X9-X12 which is what I specified when I try to apply the join/merge functions. I have tried the answer you have provided already and I still get the output that I stated above

If those join columns are all unique, the two datasets will not join on those columns (there is nothing in common). That is why the resulting "joined" dataset from the full join is just those two datasets with NAs in the columns they don't have.

The unique values from the first dataset have matching values in the second dataset... they do join together, as stated in my original post. My problem is that the values in X13 from dataset 2 are not being included in the output (NAs instead of the actual value that is presented in dataset 2)
